# Can't schedule Android Notifications Unity C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-notifications

I am trying to make a notification which will appear to the user at a specific time every day. That time should not be like: `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)` . Also it would be nice if the user chose a specific time instead of adding minutes/hours to his current time in order to get the correct time. I don't get any errors but the notification doesn't arrive. I couldn't find anything useful or close to my problem other than this (it will supposedly ring at 10:30 and will repeat after a day):

```
FireTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 10, 30, 0, 0),
RepeatInterval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0),
```

⬆️ This goes in the Android Notification Parameters when you create a new notification.